# How to pass SQL query parameters without single apostrophes using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to work with SQL Server 2012. I have a database and I need create a new user of database via code. But I do not manage with it.

First, this is my SQL query

```
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestUser
```

In SQL Server, it works well.

I have this code:

```
internal class ServerContext : DbContext
{
    public ServerContext(DbContextOptions<ServerContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

<'''>

```
DbContextOptions<ServerContext> _options;
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ServerContext>();
var connectionString = string.Format(ConnectionString.ConnectString, url, dbName, login, password);
_options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options;

using (var context = new ServerContext(_options))
{
    if (data.Count() == 0)
    {
       context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Query.CreateDbUser, new SqlParameter("@Login", "user"));
    }
}
```

<'''>

```
public static class Query
{    
     public static string CreateDbUser = "CREATE USER @Login FOR LOGIN @Login";
}
```

This query transform to:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'CREATE USER @Login FOR LOGIN @Login',N'@Login nvarchar(4)',@Login=N'User'
```

And I get this error:

> Invalid syntax around "@Login".

I think this is due to the fact that the parameter "user" is passed as a string and specified in quotes when the query is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the below statement, because a variable can't replace the name of an object:

```
exec sp_executesql N'CREATE USER @Login FOR LOGIN @Login',N'@Login nvarchar(4)',@Login=N'User'
```

This would try to create a user called `@Login`, which is invalid. You would need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@Login) + N' FOR LOGIN '+ QUOTENAME(@Login) + N';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```